# can /path/{?} be used in path in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hapi.js

I am relatively new to node.js and trying to write a route which will check the authorization of all the users if the mentioned endpoint starts with /api.
I read that for optional value ? can be used {_id?} like this but is it possible to use it like {?}. 
and How do I call this route into another route which actually does the job of GET method?

Currently the method looks like this

```
 server.route({
 method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/something/nothing/{_id?}',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            Controller.vcontroller.get(request.headers.authorization, request.params, function (err, success) {
                console.log(request.headers);
                console.log(request.headers.authorization);
                if (err) {  
                    reply(func.sendError(err));
                } else {
                    reply(func.sendSuccess(APP_CONSTANTS.STATUS_MSG.SUCCESS.DEFAULT, success)).code(200);
                }
            });
        },
        config: {
            description: 'desc',
            tags: ['api', 'order'],
            validate: {
                headers: func.authorizationHeaderObj,
                params: {
                    order_id: Joi.string().required().trim(),
                    _id: Joi.string().optional().trim()
                },
                failAction: func.failActionFunction
            },
            plugins: {
                'hapi-swagger': {
                    responseMessages: APP_CONSTANTS.swaggerDefaultResponseMessages
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

when I pass endpoint /api it should check the authorization for all the users for GET PUT POST & DELETE respectively.

In other words I want global authorisation which is route specific

Can you suggest a way to implement it?

Comment: You really need to provide a small code sample.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear that I'm understanding your question, so I'll restate what I think you're asking and then answer.  If I am not understanding, please clarify.

What I think you're asking is whether you can run a check anytime someone hits a URL path that starts with `/api`, probably for user authorization purposes.

The answer is, yes, you can just incorporate that into a middleware (though I strongly recommend [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) for all your authentication needs.

That said, if you're using [Express](http://expressjs.com), then you can just add middleware at the start of your routing like so:

```
app.use('/api', (req, res, next) => {
  // trivial implementation, not for production
  const users = ['bob', 'mari', 'hasan'];
  if (users.indexOf(req.user) >= 0) {
     // user is authorized
     return next();
  }
  // Forbidden
  return res.sendStatus(403);
});
```

Put that before your other routes, and any route starting with `/api` will pass through this first. Obviously, I'm assuming you have populated `req.user` here somehow, but if you're using Passport as I suggested that will be done for you.

Answer (score 1):

To check if all requests to endpoints starting with /api are authorised you can use middleware, i.e.

```
app.use('/api', (req, res, next) => {
  // this uses passport.js for auth, you could use something else
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {  
    return next();
  }else{
    return res.status(401).send();
  }
});
```

Comment: So What changes would be required in the existing route and how it would effect the response?

Comment: That depends on your authentication method my answer was regarding your initial question

Comment: Why did somebody -1 the answer... the original question was asking whether it was possible to verify all requests to endpoints ending in /api

Comment: simple and clever. nice.